# Create ArrayBuffer from Array (holding integers) and back again

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraybuffer

It seems so simple, but I cannot find out how to convert an `Array` filled with integers to an `ArrayBuffer` and back again to an `Array`. There are lots of examples where strings are converted to an `ArrayBuffer` like for example **[here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/06/How-to-convert-ArrayBuffer-to-and-from-String?hl=en)**.
Using these examples I created this:

```
/**
 * Convert string to array buffer.
 *
 * @param {Array.<int>} array
 * @returns {ArrayBuffer}
 */
self.arrayToArrayBuffer = function( array ) {
    var length = array.length;
    var buffer = new ArrayBuffer( length * 2 );
    var view = new Uint16Array(buffer);
    for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        view[i] = array[i];
    }
    return buffer;
}
```

Then the array also needs to converted back again. For this I use:

```
var array = new Uint16Array(arrayBuffer);
```

This solution seems to work, but is there no easier way to do this?

### UPDATE

It should also work for an array like:

```
var array = [3,7426,78921]
```

Comment: You're using `unsigned short`, not `int`. It's best to reffer to the types with exact size (eg. `uint8_t`).

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Yes, there's a simple way without manually writing a loop (the loop still exists somewhere in background):

```
new Uint16Array([1,2,3]);
```

That's all. Of course, floating numbers will be rounded down and big numbers will overflow.

#### Converting typed array to buffer

The buffer of any typed array is accessible through `.buffer` property, as [**anyone** can read on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint16Array#Properties_2):

```
new Uint16Array([1,2,3]).buffer;
```

#### Chosing the right typed array

Be warned that mentioned `Uint16Array` will only hold integers (no floating point) between zero and 65535. **To hold any javascript Number<sup>1</sup> you will want to use `Float64Array`** - the bigest one, taking 8 bytes total.

<sub>**1:** Which is unrestricted double, which appears to be 64bit [IEEE 754 number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)</sub>

Here's a map I have created that maps some of the important information related to number data types:

```
var NUMBER_TYPE = [
  {name: "uint8",   bytes:1, max:        255,       min: 0,                floating: false, array: Uint8Array},
  {name: "int8",    bytes:1, max:        127,       min: -128,             floating: false, array: Int8Array},
  {name: "uint16",  bytes:2, max:      65535,       min: 0,                floating: false, array: Uint16Array},
  {name: "int16",   bytes:2, max:      32767,       min: -32768,           floating: false, array: Int16Array},
  {name: "uint32",  bytes:4, max: 4294967295,       min: 0,                floating: false, array: Uint32Array},
  {name: "int32",   bytes:4, max: 2147483647,       min: -2147483648,      floating: false, array: Int32Array},
  {name: "float64", bytes:8, max: Number.MAX_VALUE, min: Number.MIN_VALUE, floating: true , array: Float64Array}
];
```

Float 32 is missing as I was unable to calculate necessary information for it. The map, as it is, can be used to calculate the smallest typed array you can fit a Number in:

```
function findNumberType(num) {
    // detect whether number has something after the floating point
    var float = num!==(num|0);
    // Prepare the return variable
    var type = null;
    for(var i=0,l=NUMBER_TYPE.length; i<l; i++) {
      // Assume this type by default - unless break is hit, every type ends as `float64`
      type = NUMBER_TYPE[i];
      // Comparison asserts that number is in bounds and disalows floats to be stored 
      // as integers
      if( (!float || type.floating) && num<=type.max && num>=type.min) {
          // If this breaks, the smallest data type has been chosen
          break;
      }
    }
    return type;
}
```

Used as:

```
var n = 1222;
var buffer = new (findNumberType(n).array)([n]);
```

Note that this only works if `NUMBER_TYPE` is properly ordered.

Comment: Any typed array has `.buffer` property

Comment: Okay, I accepted your answer already, but while testing I found out it doesn't work for bigger integers... How to do that then?

Comment: `Float64Array` in particular will contain any javascript number without errors. I actually already wanted to share an algorithm I created which calculates which type of array is necessary to contain any int (so that you can use the smallest necessary). But your rude attitude changed my mind.

Comment: I tested the answer, and it seemed to work fine. But then I discovered it didn't work for larger integers. Since other people will not pay attention to a answered question I unaccepted it hoping I would get more solutions that could help me out. Rather think once more about your own hostile comments like *"you will soon find yourself mistaken"* or *"But your rude attitude changed my mind"*. I hope peace is with you my friend... Thank you for all your efforts. It is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Float64Array` worked fine. I will study the documentation for sure. I want to get my head around it, but for now I am just happy with a working solution. Thanks again...

Comment: A added the information I was talking about, along with warning for other users. I apologize - my temper along with past bad experience has taken the better of me.

Comment: Nice hat @TomášZato, I still get upvotes on this question for example again yesterday and seems your answer is also scoring well. Great holidays to you!

Answer (score 4):

You can't use an ArrayBuffer directly, but you can create a typed array from a normal array by using the **from** method:

```
let typedArray = Int32Array.from([-2, -1, 0, 1, 2])
```